# How to use ROW_NUMBER() in HQL?

Tags: nhibernate, hql, row-number

My databse is MS SQL. I want to use `ROW_NUMBER()` in HQL. Is it possible? How? I know 
about [`Custom Functions`](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/04/27/Paged-data--Count-with-NHibernate-The-really-easy-way.aspx). But prefer a way that does not need to modify web.config.

**UPDATE:**

My final goal is to delete all records in a table/entity except than last n records with HQL. I don't like to load all of them in memory then deleting them.

Comment: What are you planning to do? There's always http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998560/row-number-and-nhibernate-finding-an-items-page/2034389#2034389 , but we'd need to know your needs.

Comment: @binaryhowl: please seee my update.

Comment: That sounds like a strange goal - is this a once off? Is HQL really necessary or can you just use plain SQL (using Session.CreateSqlQuery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use plain SQL for this. Mainly because of "I don't like to load all of them in memory". This is not a very object oriented task, so you don't need an ORM.

Note: plain SQL means that the session cache gets broken. You don't get any troubles as long as you don't do other stuff within the same (non-stateless) session. If you do, I would choose the OO way and actually load the items into memory.

Answer (score 1):

as of NH v2 the HQL supports delete and update statements via `IQuery.ExecuteUpdate()`. You could experiment using also the `IQuery.SetMaxResults()` and `IQuery.SetFirstResult()` (which use `ROW_NUMBER()`) to get the desired effect.

EDIT:
i experimented my self, the SetMaxResults and SetFirstResult are ignored on sql generation for ExecuteUpdate() so this will not work.

Also @ the comment below, an HQL ExecuteUpdate (and at least for DELETE) does not necessarily mean an in-memory load of object state.

Comment: This would require to load the objects into memory.

Comment: You are wrong! The hql is translated to sql and is executed to the db directly!

Comment: Yes, that's true, but there you don't have SetMaxResults available, as far as I know. To make use of SetMaxResults you need to get them into memory. That's what I actually meant, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of HQL's `ExecuteUpdate` and `Desc` ordering, similar to:

```
delete Person p1 
where p1.Id in 
            (select p2.Id 
             from Person p2 
             where rownum <= 10
             order by p2.Id desc)
```

Comment: `rownum` didn't work for me. I used SQL and `ROW_NUMBER()` by the way. Thanks.