# Equivalent of ROW_NUMBER() function in hibernate

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate, row-number

How to express the following SQL in hibernate:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SampledDate DESC) AS Row
FROM Sample
WHERE AssetId = @AssetId
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7261089/613130) you don't. You create a view with the `ROW_NUMBER()` inside.

And be aware that if you have `JOIN`s that "multiply" your rows, then your `ROW_NUMBER()` will be nearly useless unless you use the `PARTITION BY`

Comment: Yes, that’s right but I need a general solution for mysql and oracle too.