# Get PropertyInfo from property instead of name

Tags: c#, reflection

Say, for example, I've got this simple class:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public String MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The way to get the PropertyInfo for MyProperty would be:

```
typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("MyProperty");
```

**This sucks!**

Why? Easy: it will break as soon as I change the Name of the Property, it needs a lot of dedicated tests to find every location where a property is used like this, refactoring and usage trees are unable to find these kinds of access.

Ain't there any way to properly access a property? Something, that is validated on compile time?
I'd love a command like this:

```
propertyof(MyClass.MyProperty);
```

Comment: It gets worse.  If you look at WPF, you'll notice that it requires string property names for data binding and also when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.  This is now not a corner case for users of Reflection, but the general everyday use-case.  I currently rely on Resharper to help keep things in sync.

Comment: Unitesting helped me alot here, but thats about it...

Comment: Related stack overflow question with more detailed answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491429/how-to-get-the-propertyinfo-of-a-specific-property

Comment: possible duplicate of [how-to-get-the-propertyinfo-of-a-specific-property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491429/how-to-get-the-propertyinfo-of-a-specific-property)

Comment: You can use 'typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(nameof(MyProperty);' in c#6

Answer (score 6):

The closest you can come at the moment is to use an expression tree:

```
GetProperty<MyClass>(x => x.MyProperty)
```

and then suck the `PropertyInfo` out in `GetProperty` (which you'd have to write). However, that's somewhat brittle - there's no compile-time guarantee that the expression tree is only a property access.

Another alternative is to keep the property names that you're using somewhere that can be unit tested easily, and rely on that.

Basically what you want is the mythical `infoof` operator which has been talked about many times by the C# team - but which hasn't made the cut thus far :(

Comment: Looks intriguing - but how would I write GetProperty? I'm not even sure *what* it is - a generic class? Or just a generic method?
infoof sounds lovely, too bad it's not in (yet).

Answer (score 3):

In the time since this question was posted, C# 6 has been released with the [nameof operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof). This allows a property to be accessed with the following

```
PropertyInfo myPropertyInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(nameof(MyClass.MyProperty));
```

If you rename the property, this code will not compile (actually it will, since the rename will change this line of code as well if the rename is done properly).

Answer (score -2):

The whole point of reflection is to be able to access stuff at runtime. If we assume your operator would work, you already have the class information and thus the property, making the whole thing completely useless.

Comment: I already have the property? Without the name in text? How that??