# AutoMapper custom mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I have these two models

```
public class ModelA
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email_address { get; set; }
}

public class ModelB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

and I have this mapping:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<OldStudent, NewStudent>());
var newModel = Mapper.Map<NewStudent>(oldStudent);
```

Well my mapping wont work because email_address and EmailAddress cannot be mapped.

Now I want to create a logic or to insert code where the email_address will turn to EmailAddress so the mapping will work, (in short I want to remove the underscore and make it CamelCase)

I also have too many properties so I dont want to use the manual mapping (.ForMember method by automapper)

Any idea how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Mapping with AutoMapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706697/custom-mapping-with-automapper)

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#naming-conventions?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link [naming-conventions](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html?highlight=LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention#naming-conventions)

and add below lines to config.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
  cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
  cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
});
```

This would fix the issue.