# How to make AutoMapper truncate strings according to MaxLength attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a DTO I want to map to an entity. The entity has some properties decorated with the `MaxLength` attribute.

I would like AutoMapper to truncate all the strings coming from the DTO when mapping to my entity according to the `MaxLength` for each property, so that I don't get validation errors when saving the entity.

So, if entity is defined like this:

```
public class Entity 
{
    [MaxLength(10)]
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like that doing this:

```
var myDto = new MyDto() { Name = "1231321312312312312312" };
var entity = Mapper.Map<Entity>(myDto);
```

The resulting `entity` should have its `Name` limited to a maximum of 10 characters.

Comment: Honestly you should be controlling that on your DTO, and in any UI that populates it.

Comment: That's certainly doable with custom mapping but I personally don't think it's a good idea., although I don't know much about your situation.

Comment: @juharr Sorry, but I cannot do that. I don't have control over either classes.

Comment: @SuperJMN Then I'd suggest having whoever does have control fix it.  Assuming that the data is coming from a user having it truncate instead of warning up front seems bad.  If it's data that's being transferred it also seems wrong to just truncate instead of at least throwing out a warning or logging that it's being truncated, which means a bit more work than a simple mapping.

Comment: I cannot do it in my situation. The entity is generated automatically by AutoFixture from an interface and mapped to the entity with the restrictions. Since I don't have any way to filter the data, this is the best option I have. So, please, if you know how to do it, help me :)

Comment: I wasn't talking about changing the entity, I was talking about changing the DTO.

Comment: @juharr I don't have a DTO, I used just to illustrate the scenario. What I have is a proxy returned by AutoFixture, constructed from an interface. So no, I cannot modify it. Sorry. I had to simplify the question. If I told you the full explanation, the question would have been skipped by everyone :)

Comment: AutoMapper has a `ForMember` overload that takes a `Expression<Func<?,?>>` that is applied to the source value. I have no idea what that expression would have to like like though.

Comment: I think I know what you mean by "complicated" questions getting skipped, but usually over simplified ones like this get down voted and closed for lack of research and not showing code.  You've been lucky so far.

Comment: I'm confused.  AutoFixture seems to be for simplifying unit tests, so I'm not sure how you're using it.  Ultimately it sounds like you need to do what @Hintham suggests and just fill in the reflection code to get the length from the attribute on the entity.

Comment: @juharr Yes, but AutoFixture doesn't know anything about the length restrictions (and it shouldn't). It just generates strings randomly, that is the way it should work. About oversimplifying, I think the question is well explained and the reason it doesn't have any code is that I cannot show anything because I don't have anything :)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706697/custom-mapping-with-automapper) ?

Comment: @stavm, no, that way I woulds have to specify the properties one by one. I want to do it for every member of type string having a MaxLength attribute.

Comment: I assume that these are integration tests if your hitting the DB, otherwise you should be mocking that out for unit tests.  If you have requirements on the values you want to test with that AutoFixture cannot accommodate then I'm not sure AutoFixture is the correct tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's a good place to put that logic, but here is an example that should work in your case (AutoMapper 4.x): [Custom Mapping with AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706697/custom-mapping-with-automapper/31793290#31793290)

In this example, I'm reading a custom `MapTo` property on my entity, you could do the same with `MaxLength`.

Here a full example with the current version of AutoMapper (6.x)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(configuration =>
            configuration.CreateMap<Dto, Entity>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Name, e => e.ResolveUsing((dto, entity, value, context) =>
                {
                    var result = entity.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Entity.Name)).GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>();
                    return dto.MyName.Substring(0, result.Length);
                })));

        var myDto = new Dto { MyName = "asadasdfasfdaasfasdfaasfasfd12" };
        var myEntity = Mapper.Map<Dto, Entity>(myDto);
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dto
{
    public string MyName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hey @bidou! Thanks for the answer. Please, see my "autoanswer" post. I got something! Please, review it.

Answer (score 1):

**For Automapper 4.x**
I got something with this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(configuration =>
            configuration.CreateMap<Dto, Entity>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Name, e => e.MapFrom(d => d.MyName))
                .ForMember(x => x.Free, e => e.MapFrom(d => d.Free))
                .ForMember(x => x.AnotherName, e => e.MapFrom(d => d.Another))
                .LimitStrings());

        var dto = new Dto() { MyName = "asadasdfasfdaasfasdfaasfasfd12", Free = "ASFÑLASJDFÑALSKDJFÑALSKDJFAMLSDFASDFASFDASFD", Another = "blalbalblalblablalblablalblablalblablabb"};
        var entity = Mapper.Map<Entity>(dto);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> LimitStrings<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
    {
        var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
        var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);

        var existingMaps = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().First(b => b.SourceType == sourceType && b.DestinationType == destinationType);

        var propertyMaps = existingMaps.GetPropertyMaps().Where(map => !map.IsIgnored() && ((PropertyInfo)map.SourceMember).PropertyType == typeof(string));

        foreach (var propertyMap in propertyMaps)
        {
            var attr = propertyMap.DestinationProperty.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>();
            if (attr != null)
            {
                expression.ForMember(propertyMap.DestinationProperty.Name,
                    opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new StringLimiter(attr.Length, (PropertyInfo) propertyMap.SourceMember)));
            }                                            
        }

        return expression;
    }
}

public class StringLimiter : IValueResolver
{
    private readonly int length;
    private readonly PropertyInfo propertyMapSourceMember;

    public StringLimiter(int length, PropertyInfo propertyMapSourceMember)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.propertyMapSourceMember = propertyMapSourceMember ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyMapSourceMember));
    }

    public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    {
        var sourceValue = (string)propertyMapSourceMember.GetValue(source.Context.SourceValue);
        var result = new string(sourceValue.Take(length).ToArray());
        return source.New(result);
    }
}
```

Please, tell me if it has sense or has some bugs!

Thanks to @bidou for the tip. Here is the post where I took the inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706697/custom-mapping-with-automapper/31793290#31793290)

Comment: It does in this scenario, but I think there is something wrong. I don't now. Please, review it.

Comment: Looks ok for AutoMapper 4.x. If you use the latest (6.x currently) then you will have to refactore the code a bit because a lot of things are now obsolete.

Comment: Do you think you could provide us with a 6.x version of the code? Thank you!

Comment: Bidou - I'm slightly confused did you provide a 6.x version of the code somewhere?
This answer is definitely for 4.x
David Bonds answer doesn't appear to work from my testing.

Comment: @ChrisNevill yes, check my answer in this post (currently the accepted answer)

Answer (score 1):

For AutoMapper 8.0, and building on @SuperJMN's answer:

Create a file AutoMapperExtensions.cs in your project:

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace YourNamespaceHere
{
    public static class AutoMapperExtensions
    {
        public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> LimitStrings<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
        {
            var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
            var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);

            var existingMaps = Mapper.Configuration.GetAllTypeMaps().First(b => b.SourceType == sourceType && b.DestinationType == destinationType);

            var propertyMaps = existingMaps.PropertyMaps.Where(map => !map.Ignored && ((PropertyInfo)map.SourceMember).PropertyType == typeof(string));

            foreach (var propertyMap in propertyMaps)
            {
                var attr = propertyMap.DestinationMember.GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>();
                if (attr != null)
                {
                    expression.ForMember(propertyMap.DestinationMember.Name,
                        opt => opt.ConvertUsing(new StringLimiter(attr.Length), propertyMap.SourceMember.Name));
                }
            }

            return expression;
        }
    }

    public class StringLimiter : IValueConverter<string, string>
    {
        private readonly int length;
        private readonly PropertyInfo propertyMapSourceMember;

        public StringLimiter(int length)
        {
            this.length = length;
            propertyMapSourceMember = propertyMapSourceMember ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyMapSourceMember));
        }

        public string Convert(string sourceMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var sourceValue = (string)propertyMapSourceMember.GetValue(sourceMember);
            return new string(sourceValue.Take(length).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

... and add the following to the end of your CreateMap (e.g.):

```
.ForMember(
    dest => dest.ShortField,
    opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.LongField))
.LimitStrings();
```

Comment: I'm having problems with this.  I'm getting the following 
'Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.'